# Perl 5 Get input from user and delete from table in database

Tags: database, perl, input, terminal

I have a simple Perl script, I simply want to get the input from the user terminal style and use that to delete a row within the table in the database, here is the code snippet:

```
# something not right here..
my $name = <STDIN>;

my $sth3 = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM animals WHERE animal_name = ?");

$sth3->bind_param(1, $name);

$sth3->execute() or die 'nope...';
print $sth3->rows;
$sth3->finish();
```

The connection is working, however, the query will not pick up the value to delete so 0 rows are always returned. Any help would be nice with this, I believe I am going about this the right way but making a small mistake in binding this to the query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add the input and some information (content, tablestructure) about the table?

Comment: maybe `chomp $name` before you bind? Just an idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the input. Do

```
my $name = <STDIN>;
chomp($name);
```

or

```
chomp(my $name = <STDIN>);
```